# XPath for deeply nested elements?

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri.

Suppose I have a deeply nested path:

```
//h1/h2/h3/h4/h5
```

I think I can use the following path:

```
//h1/*/*/*/h5
```

Is there any way I can avoid using multiple asterisks?  Something like `//h1/.../h5`?

I don't want to keep counting the levels of nesting.

Comment: Do you need any/all `h5` tags or do you need a specific one in the HTML? If you need a specific one, do you have an ID or CLASS for `h5` that'd help you navigate to it, or something specific about the particular one that can be used as a landmark?

Comment: While pguardiario's answer is correct given the way you framed your question, as the Tin Man hints at, there is most likely a better way to target specifically the element(s) you're looking for.

Comment: @theTinMan Mark Thomas - i forgot about this question - sorry about that.  The issue was that I have one h5 as shown and another h5 in another heirarchy.  For now pguardiario's answer is very good for me.  I'll update later. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use: `//`, i.e.: `//h5`. This XPath will select all `h5` elements. See spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Answer (score 12):

for all h5 elements that descend from an h1 use:

```
//h1//h5
```

Or you might like the simpler css style:

```
h1 h5
```

Answer (score 4):

**If you want to select all `h5` that are exactly 4 levels below their h1 ancestor, use:**

```
//h5[ancestor::*[4][self::h1]]
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="//h5[ancestor::*[4][self::h1]]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>
 <head/>
 <body>
  <h1>First Main title
    <a>
     <b>
       <c>
         <h5 id="id1"/>
         <d>
           <h5 id="id2"/>
         </d>
       </c>
     </b>
    </a>
  </h1>
 </body>
</t>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of the evaluation (the selected `h1` elements (in this case just one)) is copied to the output**:

```
<h5 id="id1"/>
```

**If you don't want to count the number of the intermediate levels, butare sure that they don't exceed a certain number (say 7), you can write**:

```
//h1[descendent::*[not(position() > 7)][self::h1]]
```

**This selects any `h5` descendent of any `h1`, where the "distance" in levels between the `h1` and the descendent `h5` doesn't exceed 7**.

**Do note**:

**An expression like the below -- as suggested in other answers:**

```
//h1//h5
```

**incorrectly selects for the above document**:

```
<h5 id="id1"/>
<h5 id="id2"/>
```

**The second of the two selected `h5` elements is at a greater distance than the wanted one from its `h1` ancestor**.